# GTM event not linking to event goal in Google Analytics. Is this the correct set up?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking, event-tracking, analytics-events

I am trying to track views of YouTube videos embedded on a website. I have successfully set up an event tag in GTM using the following metrics:

[image]

The events are firing in the Real Time > Events report, as you can see here (the blacked out bit is the Video Title which is pulling from the 'Event Action' metric in GTM.

[image]

But then, when I go to set this up as a goal in GA, it's not firing as a goal. These are the details I'm putting in to set up the goal (again, the blacked out bit is the video title which is in the 'Event Action' section in GTM:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in the set up here?

Answer (score 1):

The set up was actually correct. It just takes 24 hours to pull through.

Comment: Get that badge brother